# How to store my iphone contact to new computer without erasing them

Tags: iphone, contacts

Hey,guys!!!i have one quick question about my iphone contact backup ...

I have an iphone that has all my contacts stored in it.... (phone numbers, email, addresses, etc...) and I recently bought an new computer, but I don't have any of this information stored in it.

My question is, how can I sync my iphone with to my PC without erasing the info in the iphone. I don't want my system to think that since the PC is empty it should erase every contact in the iphone. I just want to transfer everything from iphone and have a copy on PC,especially the contacts.

Appreciated your early reply.

Comment: Not off topic as it is a question about syncing with a computer.

Answer (score 2):

An iPhone can only be synced with one pc by default. However there are several howto's available on how to sync with multiple PC's by changing the library/iTunes persistent ID to match the one previously used to sync with the first computer. I've listed some below.

http://www.ismashphone.com/2009/05/how-to-sync-your-iphone-to-multiple-computers.html
http://www.andrewgrant.org/2008/03/30/how-to-sync-an-iphone-with-two-or-more-computers.html  http://theappleblog.com/2009/02/26/sync-iphone-ipod-with-multiple-computers/